# Calling the abstract base class constructor

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, abstract-base-class

The library has a class of neural network. If I create one network - all work fine, but when I create two or more networks - one of them stops learning. After several hours of searching the error I find that if I call base constructor after initialization - all networks learn fine.

```
self.create_graph(input_size, hidden_sizes, output_size)
self.eta = eta
self.alpha = alpha
super().__init__()
```

If code looks like

```
super().__init__()
self.create_graph(input_size, hidden_sizes, output_size)
self.eta = eta
self.alpha = alpha
```

networks don't learn. All sources you can find here -

https://sourceforge.net/p/meta-net-project/code/HEAD/tree/metanet/networks/artificial_networks/feedforward_network.py

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should narrow down the problem to be able to include all relevant pieces of code in the post itself.

Comment: I found that problem in forward function. It seems predesessors function of networkx library does not work as I expected. But what effect does place of a constructor call remains a mystery) Thanks

Comment: Can be related with nodes' identifiers that are being set up in `Node`'s constructor. At least that's the only *state* that is being altered.